# Build a scalable/ fluid 2 column rectangular module

Tags: css, html, layout

I am building this module in html and css I would like to avoid the use of JavaScript. 
To help explain what I'm trying to create I've attached a picture.

[image]

Box A - #left will have a picture inside.
Box B - #right will have text inside.
Neither Box A or B can overlap each other.

So far - 
I have managed to build the module relying on (%) and have got it to rescale smaller or larger depending on the width of browser. But it's not quite working how I intend it to yet.

The problem I'm facing -

When the module is scaled down to its smallest with the help of (min-width) Box B's width scales down with it. This is not what I intend to happen, Box B needs to stay a fixed (px) width while Box A rescales by a (%) width.

To overcome this problem I tried giving Box B (px) width instead of (%). This made matters worse - now when the browser is scaled down to its smallest Box B leaves the viewport & the scrollbars (x axis) takeover. Box B needs to be within the viewport even at the smallest scale.
Any ideas of how to get this working? Thanks.

Html -

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="left">Box A</div>
<div id="right">Box B</div>
</div>
```

Css -

```
#outer {
background-color:#830000;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
max-width:815px;
min-width:518px;
position:relative;
width:100%;
z-index:1;
}
/*Box A*/
#left {
background-color:#b1b1b1;
float:left;
padding-bottom:57%;
position:absolute;
width:72%;
height:10px; /* extra 10px helps show overlap of #left onto #right*/
z-index:2;
}
/*Box B*/
/*Switch between #right(px) and #right2(%) for the two outcomes I'm getting*/
#right { /* using px - Good - the width is fixed, But - should not overlap #left */
width:229px; 
background-color:#81dd27;
float:right;
padding-bottom:57%;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
#right2 { /*using % - Good - no overlapping, But - the width of 229px decreases*/
width:28%; 
background-color:#81dd27;
float:right;
padding-bottom:57%;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: could you please add your html & css workaround here

Comment: Hi Prasanth, I just added my code, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"px" and "%" is a bad idea.

Use media query and gives a fixed size for your 2 columns.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="left" id="c1">l</div>
  <div class="left" id="c2">l</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
.clear{clear:both;}
.left{float:left;height:300px;}
#main{width:100%;min-width:518px;}
#c1{background:red;width:72%;}
#c2{background:green;width:28%;}

@media screen and (max-width: 518px) {
  #c1{width:290px;}
  #c2{width:228px;}
}
```

I'm not sure that answers your question...

http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/njLyD

Comment: Your Codepen is good ColoO but I noticed until the browser width reaches 518px the green box width decreases and is already out of the browser viewport. I did ponder using media queries before tackling this module, but I would like to see if there is a way around this without using them at the moment. I've just added my html and css code, you can see what I've developed so far.

Comment: Add more picture to understand what you want.Big screen/medium screen/small screen. Ur second bloc disappear under your first blog. Is a better solution ? I think "media query" is the best solution but with more step. 3 media query.

Comment: More pictures? Basically the idea is for the module to scale up and down depending on browser scale. Yes the second block(box A)disappears - its a demo which isn't quite working. The blocks cant overlap because Box A will contain a picture and Box B text - both will need to be visible at any scale.